# display datetime and adding minutes to it

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a 2 part question:

1. I need to set the current date and time in the format `'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'`. It doesn't appear in the code I have.
2. From the dropdown if I select 'Add 15 mins' , then I need to add 15 mins to the datetime and display. How can I do this. I have already captured the event from the `TS` file.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" value= "{{dateTime}}" id="example-datetime-local-input">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                      Adjust
       </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)='newTime($event)' [value]="15">Add 15 min</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item"(click)='newTime($event)'[value]="30" >Minus 30 min</a>

         </div>
 </div>
```

**TS FILE**

```
dateTime: Date = new Date();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dateTime= new Date(); 

}

newTime(event :any){
  console.log("New Time"+ JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which uses ng-bootstrap for the dropdown:

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <input
    class="form-control"
    type="datetime-local"
    [ngModel]="dateTimeFormatted"
    id="example-datetime-local-input"
  />

    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Adjust</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="addMinutes(15)">Add 15 min</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="addMinutes(-30)">Minus 30 min</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dateTime: Date = new Date();
  dateTimeFormatted: string;

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dateTime = new Date();
    this.dateTimeFormatted = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateTime,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
  }

  addMinutes(mins) {
    this.dateTime.setMinutes(this.dateTime.getMinutes() + mins);
    this.dateTimeFormatted = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateTime,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    console.log(this.dateTime);
  }
}
```

**DEMO**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bp1vjv

Comment: In the drop down items ‘assMinutes(15) without haedcoding 15 can add a variable there ?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean.. you can actually put a variable instead of hardcoding the minutes (e.g. addMinutes(myMinutes) where myMinutes is a property of AppComponent)